# How to append data to JSON list that doesn't contains any key for that list?

Tags: python, json, list, file

```
[
  {
   "name": "name one",
   "id": 1
  },
  {
   "name": "name two",
   "id": 2
  }
]
```

I want to append object to the list in .json file. how do i do?

Comment: May be you could share some code ? When you sat object can you please share that which you want to append ?

Comment: Hi, your example is NOT JSON, its array of objects. If you want it to be a JSON format it has to be wrapped with {} and a key.

Comment: @NirGofman, looks like perfectly valid JSON to me.

Comment: @NirGofman Looks like JSON to me and can be parsed by `json.loads`.

Comment: @RitikSwami, What if you just read the contents of that file, then you add what you want to add, and finally you write it back to the file?

Comment: @NirGofman it's perfectly valid JSON. it is not mandatory to wrap it in {}

Comment: You right my bad

Comment: Hii @Shakeel. I wanted to append the same dict type of data that already contains in that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the existing json content update it and rewrite the updated list.

```
import json

with open("myfile.json", "r+") as f:
    my_file = f.read()  # read the current content
    my_list = json.loads(my_file)  # convert from json object to dictionary type
    dict_obj = {
        "name": "name three",
        "id": 3
    }
    my_list.append(dict_obj)
    f.seek(0)  # sets  point at the beginning of the file
    f.truncate()  # Clear previous content
    print(f" going to rewrite {my_list}")
    f.write(json.dumps(my_list))  # Write updated version file
```

Comment: Thank you Shakeel. It means a lot to us.

Comment: I am glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```py
import json 
   
# When loading a .json files it will be a string:
with open('data.json') as json_file:
    x = json.load(json_file) //{"key1":"123",  "key2":"456",  "key3":"789"}

    # python object to be appended 
    y = {"key4": "101112"} 
  
    # Load the json string to be an object type:
    z = json.loads(x) 
   
    # appending the data 
    z.update(y) 
  
    # the result is a JSON string: 
    print(json.dumps(z))  

    with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(z, outfile)
```

Comment: Appreciated, but how do i append it in .JSON file without having any variable assigned to it. It's a JSON file bro.

Comment: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list.

Comment: Btw thank you for your response. I got my answer. Appreciated your efforts. Thank you Nir Gofman.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what you are asking but perhaps the code below will help:

```
const myList = [
  {
   "name": "name one",
   "id": 1
  },
  {
   "name": "name two",
   "id": 2
  }
]

const myNewItem = {
   "name": "name three",
   "id": 3
  }

const addItemIfDifferentId = (list, newItem) => [...list, !list.map(({id}) =>id).includes(newItem.id) ? {...newItem} : {} ]

const newList = addItemIfDifferentId(myList, myNewItem)

newList
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Scott. But this not the ans i'm looking for.